# why the query show only duplicated rows with 2 rows only?

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to select all patients files with duplicated id no for example I have 5 files
using same id no and 20 files using same id no ,

I tried the following SELECT statement :

```
SELECT  patient_no  , id_no  , COUNT(*) 
FROM MR_PATIENT_IDS 
GROUP BY patient_no , id_no
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

but the output show only id_no duplicated 2 times and not show the greater than 2

what is the missing in the query ?

Comment: In your description you say you look for duplicate id_no. In your query you look for duplicate patient_no/id_no pairs.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner how to select duplicates if 2 times or more than 2 times I tried HAVING COUNT(*) > 2 its not show anything but in fact i have alot one id no used more than 500 times it is 0000000000 so I need to select all and update it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subquery will include all duplicated `id_no`. (with multiple `patient_no`)

Then, you use join to get your list of `patient_no` + `id_no`.

[See db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/QtkCBmqv)

```
SELECT t1.patient_no, t1.id_no
FROM MR_PATIENT_IDS t1
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT id_no, COUNT(*) AS count
  FROM MR_PATIENT_IDS 
  GROUP BY id_no
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) t2 ON t1.id_no = t2.id_no
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the below query to get the duplicate records.

`SELECT * FROM MR_PATIENT_IDS WHERE rowid not in (SELECT MIN(rowid) FROM MR_PATIENT_IDS GROUP BY patient_no, id_no);`

Comment: thank you I tried it but the output not as I need